# How to generate value of divided number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 23 teams and I want to split them into 1 to 4 groups. When I split into 2 groups it's working, but when I split them into 3-4 groups the total is not 23 teams, is there a way to share them to input text?

I thinking if the logic is like this

total teams: 23 teams
when I split into 1 group
group A: 23 teams

if I split into 2 groups
group A: 12 teams
group B: 11 teams

if I split into 3 groups
group A: 8 teams
group B: 8 teams
group C: 7 teams

so the total of the teams it still is the same

[form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnVPs.png)

```
    $('#total_group').on('change', function() {
      var total_group = $('#total_group').val();
      var participant = $('#team_ready').val();
     if (total_group != "") {
        // var first = Math.ceil(participant/total_group);
        var divided = Math.ceil(participant / total_group);
        var first = divided;
        var second = first - participant;
        var third = first - second;
        var fourth = second - third;
        var answer = [first, second, third, fourth];
        $('#split_group').css("display", "flex");
        var grouping = [];
        var alpha = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
        for (var i = 0; i < total_group; i++) {
          var content_data = "<div class='form-group' align='center' style='margin-bottom:5px;'><label>GROUP " + alpha[i] + "</label><input type='text' id='url_partner' name='url_partner' class='form-control' value='" + answer[i] + "'  required></div>";
          grouping.push(content_data);
        }
        var split_group = grouping.join('');
        $('#split_group').html(split_group);
      } else {
        $('#split_group').css("display", "none");
      }
    });
```

[my code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP3Qs.png)

please help

Comment: I dont really understand everything.  Are you trying to find a way to create as close to even teams as possible?  I am trying to follow your code, but i dont know what "participant" is.  I would love if you can give us a bigger picture so we can provide you with a proper solution

Comment: Hi, is my understanding correct that you want to group the 23 teams into 2-4 groups?

Comment: @MHornbacher yap, but when i divided into 4 group , the total is aren't 23 teams , is there anyway to divided them ?

Comment: @Fallenreaper I want to divide 23 teams into 4 groups sir, but when i select 3 or 4 group , the total of teams is not appropriate

Comment: The code you have here with `var second=;` is invalid, but your code _image_ shows `var second = first - participant;` however "participant" is not defined in either your code or your picture of code (normally pictures of code are not helpful — always copy and paste your code into your question; do not re-type your code, as you might make mistakes while re-typing)

Comment: @StephenP : sorry, this is my first time using stackoverflow ._.

Comment: Workflow:   User selects option of number of teams in which to have.  Then the desired result is a list of teams, each containing players, split as evenly as possible.   The team determining process does not take into account any sort of player skills.

Do you have a sample array containing a list of players we can use to create the functionality you request?

Comment: @FadhlihMuhammad - no problem, that's why I offered some advice. By the way, what is your goal? Roughly equal size groups? I could split 23 teams into 4 groups by doing `[20, 1, 1, 1]` but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @fadhlih 23 does not divide nicely into 2, 3, or 4. so if you are going to split them into such groups they would not have the same size. Are you sure that this is what you are trying to do?

Comment: @StephenP my goals are when i choose 1 group , GROUP A value is 23 team, but when i choose 2 group , GROUP A are 12 teams and GROUP B are 11 teams , so the value of group A and GROUP B its still 23 teams , and when i choose 3 GROUPS , group A value 8 team,GROUP B value 8 team and GROUP C value 7 teams , u know what iam means right sir ?

Comment: @Fallenreaper its just a count of number sir, so when registered teams more then 100 it can be divided into 2/3/4 and the value of each group will become 25 teams so the number of teams will still be the same as those who register

Comment: @MHornbacher : its okay, as long as the total teams are still same

team registered : 23 teams
and i split into 3 groups

so the value of each group
GROUP A : 8
GROUP B : 8
GROUP C : 7
and the total all of teams in group are still 23 but i still confused how to divided them in the right way

Comment: please share html as well

Answer (score 3):

Since 23 does not break down nicely into 2, 3 or 4 you could create a general function like so to break any array of teams into a number of groups

```
function groupTeams(teams, group_count) {
    var groups = [];
    var current_group = 0;

    for ( var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++ ) {
        // make sure that the group is an array
        if ( !groups[ current_group ] ) {
            groups[ current_group ] = []
        }
        // add the team
        groups[current_group].push( teams[i] )
        // and move to the next group
        current_group += 1;
        // go back to the beginning if we hit the end.
        if ( current_group >= group_count ) {
            current_group = 0
        }
    }

    return groups;
}
```

You can then call this function anywhere to group any number of teams into any number of groups (as you noted not always evenly)

For example:

```
var teams = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

// groups becomes array of 4 arrays containing the teams in each group
var groups = groupTeams( teams, 4 );

// and you can use the array functions to get metadata about these groups, such as their size...
var group_totals = groups.map( g => g.length )

// update UI based on groups
```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines too ... you can use `let current_group = i % group_count` as the very first thing in your for-loop, then you don't have to increment current_group and test it against group_count.

Comment: that might work. I wanted to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Personally I think it's simpler and clearer without the `+= 1` and the following `if`, using _mod_ instead {shrug}. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/ax79juzt/), viewing your browser devtools console to see the output when running it... then the [evolved version](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/ax79juzt/12/) which pre-allocates and pre-initializes the groups array (using a trick I learned [here](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/4-ways-to-populate-an-array-in-javascript-836952aea79f#579b)) ... pre-fill it with nulls then map those to new arrays.

Comment: I like your code and it is definitely better and probably what I would do in a production context. However in this case it seemed that the person asking the question seemed a bit confused so I wanted to make my answer as simple as possible and use any shortcuts (`group_count % i`) or advanced tricks (e.g. new `Array().fill().map()` to create a default array) to try and convey the idea without getting him confused and tied down in the details (e.g. how do I know `group_count % i` get me to the right place in the array...)

Comment: Why not post it as another answer and I'll give it an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#total_group').on('change',function(){
        var total_group = $('#total_group').val();
        // var participant = $('#team_ready').val();

        if(total_group!=""){
            // var first = Math.ceil(participant/total_group);
            var divided = Math.ceil(23/total_group);
            var participant = 23;
            if(total_group=="1"){
                var first=divided;
                var second=participant-first;
                var third="";
                var fourth="";
            }else if(total_group=="2"){
                var first=divided;
                var second=participant-first;
                var third="";
                var fourth="";
            }else if(total_group=="3"){
                var first=divided;
                var second=divided;
                var third=participant-first-second;
                var fourth="";
            }else if(total_group=="4"){
                var first=divided;
                var second=divided;
                var third=divided;
                var fourth=participant-first-second-third;
            }
            var answer = [first,second,third,fourth];

            $('#split_group').css("display","flex");
            var grouping=[];
            var alpha = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
            for(var i=0;i < total_group;i++){
                var content_data="<div class='form-group' align='center' style='margin-bottom:5px;'><label>GROUP "+alpha[i]+"</label><input type='text' id='url_partner' name='url_partner' class='form-control' value='"+answer[i]+"'  required></div>";
                grouping.push(content_data);
            }
            var split_group=grouping.join('');
            $('#split_group').html(split_group);
        }else{
            $('#split_group').css("display","none");
        }
    });
```